# Why do Inline::Python functions that print fail to be redirected?

Tags: python, perl, redirect, printing

Here is the simplest reproducible for my problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.16.3;
say "Got back ", test_print();
use Inline Python => <<'END_OF_PYTHON_CODE';
def test_print() -> int:
    print("In the python test print")
    return 32
END_OF_PYTHON_CODE
```

When run simply:

```
$ perl small.pl
In the python test print
Got back 32
```

But when redirected:

```
$ perl small.pl | tee foo
Got back 32
$ cat foo
Got back 32
```

What could I be doing wrong such that `Inline::Python`code fails to print to a redirected output?

Comment: What happens if you try `print('...', file=sys.stderr)`? (Or anything other than `sys.stdout`). A weird guess is that it only lets the inline code write to standard output if it's a terminal; this would be a way to rule that out.

Comment: It works for me if I prepend a call to [unbuffer](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer) like this: `unbuffer perl small.pl | tee foo`

Comment: Re "*It works for me if I prepend a call to unbuffer*", So python isn't flushing its buffers. That sounds like Python isn't properly exited?

Comment: [Reported](https://github.com/niner/inline-python-pm/issues/32)

Comment: Thank you ikegami. I need to convert a program from Perl to Python at $ and this will be an issue for logging.

Comment: Using `unbuffer` works for me in my testing. However it will be a bit tricky to use in production, so I hope that the issue is attended to soon.

Comment: The environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`, when set, will also mitigate my issue.

Answer (score 8):

`Py_Finalize()` isn't called to properly destruct the Python interpreter.

Thankfully, the module exposes this function as `py_finalize`, allowing us to call it ourselves. Add the following to your program:

```perl
END { Inline::Python::py_finalize(); }
```

---

Demo:

```perl
use feature qw( say );

use Inline Python => <<'END_OF_PYTHON_CODE';

def test_print() -> int:
    print("In the python test print")
    return 32

END_OF_PYTHON_CODE

END { Inline::Python::py_finalize() if $ARGV[0]; }

say "Got back ", test_print();
```

```
$ perl a.pl 0
In the python test print
Got back 32

$ perl a.pl 0 | cat
Got back 32

$ perl a.pl 1
In the python test print
Got back 32

$ perl a.pl 1 | cat
In the python test print
Got back 32
```

Answer (score 2):

The *complete* thing to do is:

```perl
BEGIN {
    # Unbuffer Python's output
    $ENV{PYTHONUNBUFFERED}=1;

    # Unbuffer Perl's output
    select((select(STDOUT), $|=1)[0]);
    select((select(STDERR), $|=1)[0]);
}
...
END { 
    # Shut down the Python interpreter.
    Inline::Python::py_finalize();
}
```

You must **also** unbuffer Perl's output. Thanks to ikegami who commented to that effect in a now-deleted post, and reminded me about `py_finalize()`.

Comment: Updated. Thank you.